# Start process on the other desktop, Python, Windows

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7, pywin32

I have created second desktop

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui, win32service, win32process
import pywintypes
import traceback, thread, time, cStringIO


k = win32service.CreateDesktop("ABCD2", 0, win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, None)
```

How can I start a process, say, calc.exe on the desktop "ABCD2"?

Comment: you mean the desktop `ABCD2`, not?

Comment: Oh, yes, sure, ABCD2- I have corrected

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `STARTUPINFO.lpDesktop` to the name of that desktop:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui, win32service, win32process
#import pywintypes
#import traceback, thread, time, cStringIO


hDesktop = win32service.CreateDesktop("ABCD2",
                                      0,
                                      win32con.GENERIC_ALL,
                                      None)

win32api.Sleep(500)
StartInfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
StartInfo.lpDesktop = "ABCD2"

ProcInfo = win32process.CreateProcess(
    None,
    "mspaint.exe",
    None,
    None,
    True,
    win32con.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | win32con.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    None,
    None,
    StartInfo)
```