# Start process on a specific desktop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop

How to start a Windows process on a specific Windows Desktop?

Preferably, we are looking for a solution, which is supported on Windows 8.1 as well, i.e. which does not rely on Windows 10's new task view feature. I know, that different desktops are not easily user-accessible in Windows 8.1, still, they are supported.

Our goal is to enable developers running our web test suite in the background - no interfering of the browser window with their work.

Unfortunately, a Google search didn't turn up anyhting :-(

Note: although we're using .NET/C#, we are perfectly happy with a WinAPI call as well.

Comment: @Sidewinder94: I'm not sure we are on the same page. I'm not looking for a way to start a process on one or the other screen. I'm looking for a way to start a process on a different *desktop*. A desktop may (afaik) span over all the screens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`STARTUPINFO.lpDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when creating the process via `CreateProcess`. For an example, see [Start process on the other desktop, Python, Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23694017/start-process-on-the-other-desktop-python-windows).

However, this requires having control over the process creation. To get a web test suite to run on another desktop, you'll probably have to patch this into your web test runner (e.g., `ChromeDriver`) somehow.